# Fatal error: Call to undefined function easter_date()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the easter_date from this year.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$year = date ("Y");
$easter = date ("d-M-Y", easter_date ($year));
echo "Easter " . $year . ": " . $easter . "";
?>
```

When I execute the code following error appears:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function easter_date() in

My phpVersion is 5.3.3. I'm using Linux(Ubuntu).

Have you got an idea what is missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems like your php has been compiled without `--enable-calendar` support

http://ru.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php

Answer (score 27):

If you use a `Dockerfile` based on `php:7.1`, you can install the `calendar` extension easily:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-configure calendar
```

Comment: Works well when based on php:5.6 too.

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to enable the calendar extension in php.ini:

```
extension = calendar.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked here? http://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php

> To get these functions to work, you
>   have to compile PHP with
>   **--enable-calendar** .

Answer (score 0):

You may but need not to recompile php with `--enable-calendar`. You can just install php-calendar package.

For your system (Linux/Ubuntu), you may run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-calendar
```

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't exist on OSX

Comment: OSX was just a typo. OP's system is obviously Linux, Ubuntu. I fixed the typo. However, if your system is macOS and you use either Brew or MacPorts you can install `php-calendar` package using the respective package manager.